# SwiftUI NavigationView Title Bar Taking Up Excessive Vertical Space

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm developing an iOS app with SwiftUI and facing an issue where the `NavigationView` title bar is taking up more vertical space than I'd like, and there's also excessive spacing above the first card in a `ScrollView`. This happens before I start scrolling and the space does not reduce even after applying `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`.

Here's a simplified version of my view structure:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth

struct DashboardView: View {
    @ObservedObject var tripManager: TripDataManager
    @ObservedObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    @State private var username: String
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State private var alertMessage = ""
    
    public init() {
        self.tripManager = TripDataManager()
        self.userViewModel = UserViewModel()
        self.username = ""
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    // Cards...
                }
                .onAppear {
                    fetchUserData()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Dashboard")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: HStack {
                    Button(action: { /* User Profile Action */ }) {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchUserData() {
        // Fetch user data
    }
}
```

I've tried the following:

- Ensuring .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) is set.
- Using .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) to extend the ScrollView.
- Applying negative padding to the top of the ScrollView.
- Cleaning the build folder and restarting Xcode.

None of these have resolved the issue. The navigation bar still shows with a large vertical height, and there's a gap above the first card within the ScrollView.

[image: Image of iOS Simulator showing the issue]

[image: Another Image of the iOS Simulator showing the issue]

Comment: Have you checked if you have a navigationView inside another navigation view?  I had a problem like that once and that was the issue.